# How to change TextView based onNavigationItemSelected?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, navigation-drawer

So, I essentially have a navigation drawer that runs from the elements in "navigation_menu.xml", but there is a header throughout the app with a `TextView` that I'm trying to change based on which element of the navigation drawer is selected. I've tried to use `onNavigationItemSelected`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm wondering if you could help me change the `TextView` on different items selected?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    NavigationView nvView;
    TextView tvMain;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setNavigationViewListener();

        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        NavigationView nvView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        nvView.setItemIconTintList(null);



        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nvView, navController);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        tvMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainTitle);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

//I have also tried using the case (R.id.nav_home), (R.id.nav_members), etc for this and it doesn't work

            case 0:{
                tvMain.setText("Realtas");
                        break;
            }
            case 1:{
                tvMain.setText("Members Fragment");
                break;
            }

    }
    return true;}

    private void setNavigationViewListener(){
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```

And heres the menu/navigation_menu.xml

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_members"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_members"
        android:title="@string/menu_members" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ireland"
        android:title="@string/menu_map" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_news"
        android:title="@string/menu_news" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_livestream"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_livestream"
        android:title="@string/menu_livestream" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_election"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_election"
        android:title="@string/menu_election" />

    <item android:title="@string/menu_misc">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"
        android:title="@string/menu_login"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_register"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_harp_circle"
            android:title="@string/menu_register"/>




    </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="Irish Version">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gaeilge"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_gaeilge"
                android:title="@string/menu_gaeilge"/>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Also heres the navigation/main.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_members"
            app:destination="@id/nav_members" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_election"
            app:destination="@id/nav_election" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_login"
            app:destination="@id/nav_login" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_map"
            app:destination="@id/nav_map" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_register"
            app:destination="@id/nav_register" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_livestream"
            app:destination="@id/nav_livestream" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_news"
            app:destination="@id/nav_news" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_members"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.MembersFragment"
        android:label="Members"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_members" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_map"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.MapFragment"
        android:label="Interactive Map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_map_to_dublinMapFragment"
            app:destination="@id/dublinMapFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_close_exit"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_news"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.NewsFragment"
        android:label="Election News"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_election"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.ElectionFinalFragment"
        android:label="Upcoming Election"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_election" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_election_to_electionResultsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_election_results"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_close_exit"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_election_to_electionFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_election_map"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_close_exit"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_election_to_nav_check_register"
            app:destination="@id/nav_check_register"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_close_exit"/>
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_register"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="Register"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/nav_gaeilge"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.MainActivityGaeilge"
        android:label="Home Gaeilge"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main_gaeilge" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dublinMapFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.DublinMapFragment"
        android:label="fragment_dublin_map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dublin_map" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/livestreamHighlightsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.LivestreamHighlightsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_livestream_highlights"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_livestream_highlights" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_livestream"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.LivestreamFragment"
        android:label="fragment_livestream"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_livestream" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_livestream_to_livestreamHighlightsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/livestreamHighlightsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_check_register"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.CheckRegisterFragment"
        android:label="fragment_check_register"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_check_register" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_election_results"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.ElectionResultsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_election_results"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_election_results" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_election_map"
        android:name="com.example.fypfinaltrial.ElectionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_election"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_election" />


</navigation>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugger on the specific point ?

Comment: Problem is on the item.getItemId() are your cases values are same with the item.getitemId() ??

Comment: Everything works perfectly. But it just seems that when I want to change the TextView of tvMain, it just stays the same. No error, no nothing, just no improvement

Comment: The item.getItemId() is not matching with the cases that you have added. you have to use the Menu item id, post the Menu xml code I will give the answer I got the issue

Comment: instead of ```case 0:```, ```case 1:``` use the id's of items inside your navigation drawer. like ```case R.id.nav_item1``` , ```case R.id.nav_item2``` etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cases values with your menu xml item's id, your switch cases value are not matching with item id.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.your_menu_item_id:
                //do what you want  
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that before and it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in item.getItemId()
instead of using index in your case statements you should use id corresponds to every menu from your navigation_menu.xml

for example:
navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_realtas"
        android:title="@string/realtas" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_members"
        android:title="@string/members" />
</menu>
```

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        tvMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainTitle);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_realtas:{
                tvMain.setText("Realtas");
                        break;
            }
            case R.id.navigation_members:{
                tvMain.setText("Members Fragment");
                break;
            }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but for some reason this doesn't work? I'm confused as to why, because it worked in other situations throughout the application?

Comment: Hey, can you post your navigation_menu.xml as well?

Comment: posted it there in the main thing @mnleano